# handling nested file include in php and returning value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

In `login.php` on button click I execute `redirect.php`. 
This redirect.php perform twitter authentication. For that it invokes some other file which in turn invokes `index.php`.

`index.php` gives result `name` and `id`, which I want to retrieve in `index.php`.

source code : [Git source code](https://github.com/karimkhanp/twitteroauth)

Currently what happens, login.php executes `$.get()` before response from `login.php` and alerts `indefined value`

login.php

```
    <body>
            <input type="button" value="Run somePHPfile.php" id = "b1" />
    <script>    
    $('#b1').click(function () {
        window.location.href = 'redirect.php';    

//This function needs improvement i think, is this correct place for this to get json value from index.php??
    $.get('index.php', function(data) { //If I put this out side click then it gives undefined value for name and id before redirect.php gets executed
        // data.id is the id
            var id= data.id;
            var name = data.name;
            alert(name);
            });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
```

redirect.php

```
<?php

/* Start session and load library. */
session_start();
require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
require_once('config.php');

... //some other processing
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    require_once('twitteroauth/twitteroauth.php');
    require_once('config.php');

    if (empty($_SESSION['access_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token']) || empty($_SESSION['access_token']['oauth_token_secret'])) {
        header('Location: ./clearsessions.php');
    }
    $access_token = $_SESSION['access_token'];
    $connection = new TwitterOAuth(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, $access_token['oauth_token'], $access_token['oauth_token_secret']);
    $content = $connection->get('account/verify_credentials');
    $twitteruser = $content->{'screen_name'};
    $notweets = 5;
    $tweets = $connection->get("https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=".$twitteruser."&count=".$notweets);

        $name = $content->{'name'}; 
    $id = $content->{'id'}; 
echo json_encode((object) array('id' => $id, 'name' => $name)); //to retreive in login.php
?>
```

**UPDATE**

$.get('index.php', function(data) {
   var  user_id= data.id;
   var name = data.name;
        alert(name);
  // alert(name);
        window.location.href = 'button.php';

},"json");

Answer (score 2):

since your php file is outputting a json string your get call needs to know that it is retriving such

```
$.get('index.php', function(data) {
   var id= data.id;
   var name = data.name;
   alert(name);
},"json");
```

This will let jquery know that it needs to parse the incoming data as a json string and parse it to an object, otherwise you would have to do the parse yourself

```
$.get('index.php', function(data) {
   data = JSON.parse(data);
   var id= data.id;
   var name = data.name;
   alert(name);
});
```

Comment: thanks, I receive values successfully in login.php. But please see index.php. It browser does not come back to `login.php`. It stops at `index.php` and shows `{"id":200582436,"name":"Karimkhan"}` on screen

Comment: I want flow like `login.php - > redirect.php -> index.php (echo json values) - > login.php (move back to main page)`. Currently it is `login.php - > redirect.php -> index.php`

Comment: If I use `header("location:../../login.php");` then will `login.php` able to retreive name and id ? Even after I used it, it does not redirect to login page